# How can I successively trigger an AppleScript very quickly?

Tags: software-recommendation, applescript, audio

### Background

For fine volume adjustment I use the following AppleScript:

```
try
    do shell script "killall afplay"
end try
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
set volume output volume (currentVolume + 2)
    -- play volume changing sound at new volume
do shell script "afplay /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/volume.aiff"
```

This will increase the volume by 2% and play the new volume once like usual.

### Problem

Using this script has disadvantages:

- When I trigger the script quickly multiple times in a row, it does not respond as quickly as the 'normal' volume change would.
- For every execution the volume sound is played at full length.

It appears that my problem is due to a limitation of the **how the scripts are triggered**. E.g. When I use FastScript, it will not execute the script again *before* it has been finished. The same goes for Quicksilver.

However, when I assign the "lower volume script" to Quicksilver and the "louder volume script" to FastScripts I *can* trigger both scripts very fast after each other - so: the script is fine. I believe that my problem is due to how the scripts are triggered.

### Question

How can I successively trigger a script very fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to the end of the `do shell script` command should work. This redirects the `stdout` and `stderr` of the `do shell script` command to `/dev/null` and runs the shell script in the background, meaning that AppleScript no longer needs to wait for the command to return `stdout` or `stderr` before the AppleScript script can finish. That means that it finishes and can be run again much more quickly.

You also shouldn't need the `try` handler at the beginning. The following modified script should work:

```
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
set volume output volume (currentVolume + 2)
-- play volume changing sound at new volume
do shell script "afplay /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/volume.aiff > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

I got this tip from MacScripter (an excellent resource for AppleScripting) in a [post](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=29446) about running multiple instances of a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an ampersand to the end of the `afplay` line so the scripted part plays in background? Like this

```
afplay /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/volume.aiff &
```

Comment: I did get the syntax of that slightly wrong (quotes in the wrong place). It should have been `afplay /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/volume.aiff &`. Not saying that will help, just wanting to correct myself :-)